# DuckDB file name should not be "temp.duckdb"

Tags: r, duckdb

It appears that DuckDB or at least the R library `duckdb` has reserved the filename `temp.duckdb`. If DuckDB file name is set as `temp.duckdb`, the error thrown `Error: Parser Error: Only TEMPORARY table names can use the "temp" catalog` may not be clear to all. Here is the reprex throwing parser error:

```
library("glue")
library("duckdb")
#> Warning: package 'duckdb' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Loading required package: DBI
#> Warning: package 'DBI' was built under R version 4.2.3
library("dplyr")
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

# set temporary directory as working directory
setwd(tempdir())

con <-
    DBI::dbConnect(
        duckdb(),
        dbdir = "temp.duckdb"
    )

duckdb_register(con, "mtcars", mtcars)

# make DuckDB native table using registered dataframe (or cvs / parquet)
tbl(con, "mtcars") |> 
    compute(name = "mtcars_native", temporary = FALSE)
#> Error in `db_save_query.DBIConnection()`:
#> ! Can't save query to "mtcars_native".
#> Caused by error:
#> ! rapi_prepare: Failed to prepare query CREATE TABLE 
#> mtcars_native AS
#> SELECT *
#> FROM mtcars
#> Error: Parser Error: Only TEMPORARY table names can use the "temp" catalog
```

It may be intentional as the in-memory DuckDB may use `temp` keyword. But, nevertheless, `temp` is a pretty common name during quick testing and someone else might get puzzled as I was. Self answering it for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the duckDB file name from `temp.duckdb` to `temp1.duckdb` works.

```
con <-
    DBI::dbConnect(
        duckdb(),
        dbdir = "temp1.duckdb"
    )
```